# Git status showing weird untracked "path_of_file\r" files, how to remove by command line

Tags: c++, git, bash, command-line

I was in a C++ program with google unit test, gtest. I ran and built the projects.

At the end, when I ran `git status`, it gave some weird untracked files. I do not know where they are from, and how I should remove them please. Using bash.

```
> git status
On branch A
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    "../path_of_file1\r"
    "../path_of_file2\r"
    "../path_of_file3\r"

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

This did not work:

```
rm -f "path_to_file\r"
```

Thank you.

I believe `git clean` should work in most scenarios. I tried the rm without the "", it worked! Thank you all. 
rm path_to_file\r  (complete by tabs)

Comment: Do those paths exist?

Comment: Don't update your post with your solution. If none of the available solutions works as written you can write your own and accept that. If one did work (even with slight modifications) then accept that answer (and add a comment explaining why you needed modifications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David's answer is a good one, assuming you want to do a full `git clean`.

Here is another option that lets you delete the files individually: Let your shell complete the file names for you, escaping them as necessary.

For example, if you type

```
rm path_to_file1
```

and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, most shells will complete the filename with a proper escape sequence. The precise sequence will be shell-specific, and I'm not clear whether `\r` is the two characters `\` and `r` or whether it's a single special character, but your shell will know for sure.

Comment: I believe `git clean` should work. I tried 
`rm path_to_file1\r`
without the quotes, and when types path_to_file1, continued using tab, and then it worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can always remove all untracked (and unignored) files with `git clean -f`. To be safe, run `git clean -n` first to see which files will be deleted.